# How do I configure a website project to use IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have a website project, not a web application.  I have Visual Studio SP1 (beta) installed, but I only see the option to use an external web server; there is no "Use IIS Express" option like with web applications.

Is this supported? If so, how do I set it up to use IIS Express?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1 as well as IIS Express and I found a right-click option on my web project called "Use IIS Express". Scott Guthrie talks about it here:  [VS 2010 SP1 (Beta) and IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx) .

Answer (score 2):

VS 2010 SP1 beta has support for IIS Express. I am not sure if you have installed IIS Express separately or not (VS 2010 SP1 does not include IIS Express and you need to install it separately). If you haven't installed IIS Express install it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=iisexpress)

Comment: @user578913 I have installed both. I do not see where to configure IIS Express, in the website property pages.

Comment: When you are creating new Website project, you can choose the webserver you want to use. File -> New -> Web Site -> choose HTTP from 'Web location' drop down and click browse button and here you should find some option to choose IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Support for IIS Express will not come until Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1 is released later this year.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed but I mentioned that I have installed SP1 beta, which offers support for IIS Express.  Perhaps the beta does not support IIS Express with website projects though?

Comment: @JimGeurts I read that it you had installed the beta and that was my conclusion is that it will be released in the final version of the SP1 release, they may still be working on it. Sorry should have clarified.