# use IIS Express NOT appear in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2010

I Installed SP1 RTM in my visual studio 2010.
and installed IIS Express correctly.
(using korean language in VS2010.)

BUT.. I CANT SEE WORDS LIKE IIS EXPRESS

Tools -> Options -> Show All Checked -> Project and Solutions -> ...?
(I cant see Web Projects section.)

well.. looking for IIS Express in existing web project.
right mouse click -> over the debug.. but I cant see "USE IIS EXPRESS"

Okay. I'd like find IIS Express in Project Properties.
mouse right click -> properties

click a Web tab. just find use local IIS but not showing IIS EXPRESS.

orz.. what can I do?:(

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030152/how-do-i-configure-a-website-project-to-use-iis-express

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch VS 2010.
2. Locate your Website Project in the Solution Explorer tree view.
3. Right-click on your Website project name and select the **Use IIS Express...** option.

Hope this helps.!

[IIS Express in VS 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ourjB.png)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I'd opened the site USING IIS - so I didn't get the option to 'Use IIS Express' because it HAD to use IIS. Removing the project and re-opening it from the file-system gave me the option back :)