# How to change Web.Config to allow PHP handling in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013

I am working on editing the WordPress 3.8.1 code in Visual Studio 2013 with Update 1.  Over time I want to be able to write C#.NET plugins for WordPress.  I have "PHP Tools for Visual Studio" installed.  My current web.config file contents is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

When I run the website and navigate to the index.php I get an error relating to the fact that .php files are not being handled.

---

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

---

What do I need to add the web.config file such that the .php files are handled properly and yet still be able to run in debug mode using the PHP Tools for Visual Studio?  Is or there some other setting I need to change?

---

EDIT:

I am one step further along. When running in VS2013, IIS Express is used and this was not configured to handle PHP files. The following commands were sent from the command line to fix that:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"']    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"',resourceType='Unspecified']
```

You'd have to check the paths for your own installation. (Thanks to [Enabling PHP on IIS Express with Visual Studio (sans WebMatrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099143/enabling-php-on-iis-express-with-visual-studio-sans-webmatrix))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was with how I installed "PHP Tools for Visual Studio" (I'd already installed PHP and XDEBUG separately rather than allowing "PHP Tools" to install them automatically) and then how I imported the WordPress files into Visual Studio 2013 (I opened them as a Web Site rather than starting with a PHP Web Project, and dropping the WordPress files into that).  If you follow the screencast at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otfHuSzxYnw&list=UURc_zRmw1Lql59cAqT85cmA it works just fine.