# Office Task Pane add-in with c# libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, office-interop, office-js

I have this Office task pane add-in, which is based in javascript.
However, I'm making PHP calls, and in order them to work correctly, I created **Web API 2 Controllers** and added them to the project, so each ajax call is basically just calling the C# controllers.

1. What is the most lightweight thing, that I have to install on our server, in order to get these ASP.NET controllers to work?
2. I'm using multiple other libraries in each of my controllers. Will those be packaged as well, or do I have to copy them in the same library as where the controllers are?
3. Can I use interop libraries for the specific Office application? The javascript API offers very little, and it lacks some of the most needed features.

PS: I followed this tutorial

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Why did you add the .Net layer? Your front end JavaScript doesn't care what language the back end is running.

Comment: lgaud is right. Maybe explain a bit more what you have as constraints to pick such an architecture. To answer your question, it depends on your OS. Check if you can install IIS Express (related http://stackoverflow.com/a/6100101/311063). It will run your .NET API project in most cases. Alternatively, hosting the whole app, including PHP, on Server 2012 R2 is possible https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592(v=ws.11).aspx